# MySQL query to return counts of rows by month

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli, prepared-statement

I'm trying to get `counts` of the `number of rows` in a `table` for the last `12 months`, on a month by month basis to give `12 counts`.

So far, I have this really ugly way of doing it:

```
SELECT (
    SELECT COUNT(i.id) FROM intrusions i, devices d WHERE i.device_id = d.id AND d.primary_owner_id = '1' AND FROM_UNIXTIME(start_time/1000) like '2014-04%',
    SELECT COUNT(i.id) FROM intrusions i, devices d WHERE i.device_id = d.id AND d.primary_owner_id = '1' AND FROM_UNIXTIME(start_time/1000) like '2014-03%',
    SELECT COUNT(i.id) FROM intrusions i, devices d WHERE i.device_id = d.id AND d.primary_owner_id = '1' AND FROM_UNIXTIME(start_time/1000) like '2014-02%',
    etc
)
```

The tables are set up so `1 user` can have `many devices` and `1 device` can have `many intrusions`, hence the extra conditions.

The `primary_owner_id` and the `date` will be added in dynamically in `PHP` using `prepared statements`. Is there a better way to write this out which wouldn't involve so much repitition and binding 24 parameters? Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Can't you just do a `GROUP BY`?

Answer (score 0):

You should use grouping to get this. So something like this.

```
SELECT
    CONCAT(YEAR(FROM_UNIXTIME(start_time/1000)), '-', MONTH(FROM_UNIXTIME(start_time/1000))) AS `year_month`,
    COUNT(id) AS `count`
FROM intrusions AS i
INNER JOIN devices AS d
  ON i.device_id = d.id
WHERE d.primary_owner = ?
GROUP BY `year_month`
ORDER BY `year_month` DESC
LIMIT 12
```

Comment: You are awesome, thanks! The only downside is that it returns 12 counts regardless of whether they are within the last year. Instead of returning zero for a particular month with no rows, it skips it and moves to the next. Not a massive problem though

Answer (score 0):

You can use DATE_FORMAT to select the Year and Month, and you can use DATE_SUB to create a WHERE condition selecting items in the last month.  Haven't tested this syntax but it should be close to correct.

This is along the same lines as the last answer but improves by firstly using the more succinct DATE_FORMAT and using DATE_SUB to automatically select the last 12 months

```
SELECT
  DATE_FORMAT(start_date, "%Y-%m") AS `month`,
  COUNT(`id`) AS `count`
FROM intrusions
INNER JOIN devices ON (intrusions.device_id = devices.id)
WHERE
  d.primary_owner_id = 1 AND
  DATE_SUB(CUR_DATE(), INTERVAL 12 MONTH) < start_date
GROUP BY month
ORDER BY month DESC
```

Comment: I tried this query but only seem to be getting 1 set of counts of the last 12 months

Comment: Change start_date refrences to FROM_UNIXTIME(start_date/1000).  But you would be better to consider using MySQL 5.6 with native fractional seconds support, rather than storing the unix time as an integer. dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/fractional-seconds.html

Comment: Ah it works well now using FROM_UNIXTIME() and gives a count by month but doesn't seem to limit to the last 12 months?